# Search in NASM structure

Tags: assembly, nasm

Search in NASM structure.

I have structure {string ; num}, I need to do search in this structure by console input. I enter string and must output num  of this string in structure, but dont working.

I think problem in this string (in search label).

```
mov esi, [ebx + record.txt]; take the text
```

And else i dont know how take number from structure and output it ( in success label).

```
mov ecx, ebx; in ecx text address
add ecx, record.num;
```

All code

```
global Start
STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE equ -11
STD_INPUT_HANDLE  equ -10
EXTERN GetStdHandle
EXTERN WriteFile
EXTERN ExitProcess
EXTERN ReadConsoleA
extern lfwrit

section .text

Start:
    ; get the handle of the output
    push dword STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
    call GetStdHandle
    mov [hstdout], eax
    mov eax, 1000h

    ; WriteFile (hstdout, txt, 7, & actlen, NULL)
    push 0
    push actlen
    push msg_len
    push msg
    push dword [hstdout]
    call WriteFile

    ; get an input handle
    push dword STD_INPUT_HANDLE
    call GetStdHandle
    mov [hstdin], eax

    ; ReadConsoleInputA (hstdin, buf, buf_len, 0);
    push 0
    push actlen2; Pointer to a DWORD for number of characters read to be returned
    push 11
    push string
    push dword [hstdin]
    call ReadConsoleA


    mov ebx, records
    mov ecx, [records_count]
        
search:

    mov esi, [ebx + record.txt]; take the text
    mov edi, string; entered string
    mov ebx, 11; maximum length
    cld
    repe cmpsb; compare strings
    jecxz success
    add ebx, 15; I add 15 cos txt 11 bytes + 4 bytes num
    loop search

    ; WriteFile (hstdout, txt, 7, & actlen, NULL)
    ; Fail
    push 0
    push actlen
    push fail_msg_len
    push fail_msg
    push dword [hstdout]
    call WriteFile

    jmp _exit

success:

    mov ecx, ebx; in ecx text address
    add ecx, record.num;
    mov eax, ecx



    ; WriteFile (hstdout, txt, 7, & actlen, NULL)
    ; num
    push 0
    push actlen
    push dword 4
    push eax
    push dword [hstdout]
    call WriteFile

    call lfwrit

_exit:
    ;ExitProcess(0)
    push dword 0
    call ExitProcess


section .bss
    string resb 11; space for the entered string
    struc record; structure number - text
    .txt resb 11
    .num resd 1
    endstruc

section .data
    ; handles
     hstdout dd 0
     hstdin dd 0
     actlen dd 1; something to input
     actlen2 dd 1; something to output

     teststr db 'hiiiiiiiiii'
     msg db 'Entex text:', 0ah
     msg_len equ $ - msg
     fail_msg db 'Note with this text doestn exist', 0ah
     fail_msg_len equ $ - fail_msg
; structure initialization
records:
    istruc record
        at record.txt, db 'hiiiiiiiiii'
        at record.num, dd 1
    iend
    istruc record
        at record.txt, db 'Descriptioo'
        at record.num, dd 2
      
    iend
    istruc record
        at record.txt, db 'Loremipsum'
        at record.num, dd 3

      
    iend
    istruc record
        at record.txt, db 'Dolorsitam'
        at record.num, dd 4
      
    iend
    istruc record
        at record.txt, db 'Note-5'
        at record.num, dd 5
      
    iend

    records_count dd 5
```

Comment: That should be a `lea` to get the address.

Comment: `repe cmpsb` expects a count in `ecx` but you're apparently intending `ebx` to be used. And `jecxz` is not the right condition, it needs to be `je`. And you need to preserve `ecx` around the `repe cmpsb` for the `loop` instruction to work. Here's [an example](https://hg.ulukai.org/ecm/ldebug/file/a9dc0c52ab83/source/boot.asm#l2651) (for 8086 assembly) of using `repe cmpsb` with `di` pointing to a structure and being incremented to point to the next structure entry after the comparison.

Comment: wow,thank you so much, search is working, I did everything as you said, but in output smiles (https://prnt.sc/12ksrou)

Comment: Use `mov eax, dword [POINTER + record.num]` where `POINTER` is `ebx` or `edi` or whatever you're using as a pointer to the record. Then search for [how to display an integer in assembly](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com%20display%20integer%20x86%20assembly).

Comment: Thanks, you are a genius, program works!

Comment: But one more question, its work only with 11 (max) letters strings. I think, cos ReadConsoleA read enter-key. Do you know how ignore enter-key?